# Windows Batch Script - Matching numbers from text file

Tags: batch-file

I am new to batch script,i would like to know how to match numbers(not line numbers) say 1,2,3 to a text file(a.txt).

If any other number matches it should alert me and if it matches the number which im looking for then it should print success.

Any advise or help ? i tried findstr and if condition but i couldn't work it out, as i said im newbie so please help me

Thanks
Hari

Comment: The question is too vague to attempt a solution.  Can you provide an example input file?  Where do these numbers (1,2,3) come from?  Are they operator input, another file, hard coded????  Also show an example of the desired output.

Comment: @RGuggisberg - Hi, Sorry for not making myself clear over here. Those numbers(1,2,3) are already in a.txt file. so when i check the file(a.txt) using a script, it should alert me if there are any unexpected number. eg: if number "4" is there in "a.txt" it should alert me. Hope its some what clear now. thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't quite understand what is trying to be said here but I think the author is trying to find out is the following:

- *Can you check if a txt file named a.txt contains 1,2,3 (or any other number series separated by a ",") and if there are no other numbers in the file then it will alert the user and not `Echo` the file name ?*

---

### Solution:

```
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
setlocal enableextensions
set file=Ok
set target=a.txt

for /f "delims=, tokens=1-3" %%a in (%target%) do (
    call :Check %%a %%b %%c
)
:Check
if exist %1 (
if %1 neq 1 if %1 neq 2 if %1 neq 3 (set file=Alert
) else (shift /1)
goto :Check
) else (goto :report)
goto :eof

:report
if %file% equ Alert echo %target% does not match
if %file% equ Ok (
echo %target% is fine
Rem ! ! ! Add what you want to do to file here
)
```

OK, so this will only work if the file only has 1 line. It may need to be tweaked cause I'm not sure if it will work (tell me if it doesn't work). Pretty much, where it says `tokens=1-3`, that's the length of the series. `call :Check %%a %%b %%c` is to implement each one so if there were 4 in the series these would become `tokens=1-4`, `call :Check %%a %%b %%c %%d`.

Lastly in the `:check` procedure the `if %1 neq 1 if %1 neq 2 if %1 neq 3` includes the numbers you want the series to consist of, (**Note it doesnt check for order**). so if you want ed to include 4 it would be `if %1 neq 1 if %1 neq 2 if %1 neq 3 if %1 neq 4`.

Again im not sure if this will work with as I haven't tested it and if anyone wants to suggest changes or tell me how to fix it feel free. If the concept of it is wrong (I'm confident its not) tell me and I'll delete this answer.